# How to prove by modular arithmetic

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes and let $N=pq$. Let $k=(p-1)(q-1)$. For each e with $\gcd(e,k)=1$, by Proposition 3.5 there is $d$ satisfying $de=1 \pmod k $. Prove that $n^{de}=n \pmod N$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Proposition 3.5: Suppose $\gcd(c,m)=1$. If $cx=cy \pmod m$, then $x=y \pmod m$; moreover, for any b, the congruence $cx=b \pmod m$ has a solution, and any two solutions are congruent (mod m).

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know about Fermat's Little Theorem and the Euler-Fermat Theorem?

Comment: I am clueless on how to solve this. Fermat's Little Theorem is in the text but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: So, Fermat's Little Theorem says that if $p$ is prime and $p$ does not divide $a$, then $$a^p\equiv a\mod p\ .$$
The Euler-Fermat theorem generalises this to when you don't have a prime, it says that if gcd$(a,n)=1$, then $$a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n\ .$$
The first thing to do is make sure that you understand these two results, then see if you can see the connection between them and what you're trying to prove.

Answer (score 1):

A few hints/things you need to notice:

Firstly, if you have that $de \equiv$ $1$ $($ $mod$ $k)$, this means that $de = mk +1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

You can now substitute this in to what you're trying to prove.

You now need to work out what $\phi(N)$ is, expressed in terms of $p$ and $q$.

Now, given your previous substitution, notice that if $n$ is co-prime to $N$ you're now practically done, by the Euler-Fermat Theorem.

You then have to figure out what's going on if $n$ is not co-prime to $N$ (IE gcd($n$,$N$) $\neq 1$). In this case $n$ is either a multiple of $p$, a multiple of $q$, or a multiple of both $p$ and $q$.

Summary:

$de \equiv 1 \mod k \iff de = mk + 1$ for  $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Now

$n^{de} \equiv n \mod N \iff n^{mk+1} \equiv n \mod N  \iff n*(n^{m})^{k} \equiv n \mod N$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

and following the hints above, you should probably be able to finish this off.

Comment: If you are going to use Euler's totient function, then what you really want is $n \cdot (n^k)^m$